# Need some information on jdeb plugin control file

Tags: java, maven-3

I am facing a problem with jdeb plugin.I have to modify the jdeb plugin (integrated with maven)such that the name of the debian file created shall have a different name then the current name and the control file generated should have the modified name.Now i am able to modify the current name but i am still getting the old package name in my control file.

```
    Please find my plugin written below.

 <plugin>
            <artifactId>jdeb</artifactId>
             <groupId>org.vafer</groupId>
             <version>0.11-nklasens-1</version>
             <executions>
                     <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                  <goal>jdeb</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                    <deb>${project.build.directory}/ABC_${version}.deb</deb>
                                    <timestamped>true</timestamped>
                                    <controlInfo>
                                            <priority>${debian.priority}</priority>
                                            <section>${debian.section}</section>
                                             <architecture>${debian.architecture}</architecture>
                                             <description>${debian.description}</description>
                                              <maintainer>${debian.maintainer}</maintainer>
                                      </controlInfo>
                            <dataSet>
                                     <data>
                                          <src>${project.build.directory}/ABC.war</src>
                                          <type>file</type>
                                          <destName>ABC.war</destName>
                                           <mapper>
                                                     <type>perm</type>
                                                     <prefix>/srv/tomcat/webapps</prefix>
                                                     <user>tomcat</user>
                                                     <group>tomcat</group>
                                                     <filemode>644</filemode>
                                            </mapper>
                                     </data>
                            </dataSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
           </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

got the answer after doing some experiment

The answer is add below tags under  tag

```
<packageName>ABC</packageName>
<version>${version}</version>
```